# Dependency missing from the artifactory. How to find which pom requires it?

Tags: java, maven

I have kinda strange problem. Maven is not able to download one of the **internal** dependencies - this dependency doesn't exist in artifactory for version that is required. I want to find where it comes from, so I can update pom file to specify correct version.

Let's call this dependency `com.x.y`

What was tried:

- Checking all poms in project - no `com.x.y` anywhere. I was using both `grep` command and later manually going through the files.
- I have checked bitbucket, all connected projects using find option. There was dependency `com.x.y` in some of the poms, but in different versions (so it didn't help)
- I grepped my `~/.m2/repositories` - it did find dependency, but in the different version.
- Obviosly I've tried various `mvn dependency:tree` and `mvn dependency:analyze` - command failed, because, well, it wasn't able to download `com.x.y` from the artifactory (maybe there is some switch to make it work? I couldn't find any).

So, how do I find out where this dependency is defined?

Comment: Did you try mvn -X ... ?

Comment: Yes, it didn't help :)

Comment: Which version is defined? Is it a SNAPSHOT version? If it's not there maven can not download ... which Maven version do you use? Please show the log output ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, what actually helped was to create mock-library with the same version and name as the original and put it in my .m2 folder. This wasy `dependency:tree` command finished successfully.